# revisar existencia de varios archivos en javascript

Tags: javascript, eventos, array

El siguiente SCRIPT revisa la existencia de archivos cuyos nombres estan en un Array, si no existe el archivo muestra un aviso
La salida se hace a traves de una tabla.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
var pagina = ['pepito.html', 'IndexModeloWeb3.html', 'ProgressBar2.html', 'ProgressBar.html']
for (var t = 0; t < pagina.length; t++) {

  var mensaje = pagina[t];

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var element1 = document.createTextNode(mensaje);
  cell1.appendChild(element1);

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell2.id = t + 1;
  var element2 = document.createTextNode("")
  cell2.appendChild(element2);
}

function get_error() {
  document.getElementById(j).innerHTML = " does not exist.";
}


for (var j = 0; j < pagina.length; j++) {
  alert = (" ");

  var el = document.createElement('script');
  el.onerror = function() {
    if (el.onerror) {
      get_error(this.id);
    }
  }

  el.src = pagina[j];
  document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].appendChild(el);

}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}
```

```html
<table id="dataTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Index.html</td>
      <td>does not exists</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>progressBar.html</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>progressBar2.html</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

El problema es que NO necesito el alert; sin embargo, si lo quito del codigo, no genera el resultado como debe ser;

¿Qué puedo hacer para arreglar esto?

Comment: ¿cómo es el resultado que debe ser? ¿Podrías agregar el código HTML por fa? Te falta agregar el parámetro que debe recibir la función `get_error()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a que:

- En al función `get_error`, se esta consumiendo la variable `j`, para identificar el elemento a actualizar.
- Al remover el `alert` y como el evento `onerror` se dispara en algún momento en el futuro (`evento asincrónico`), para cuando sucede el evento el valor de la varibale `j` es distinto del que se esperaba.

### Solución:

Cuando el evento `onerror` se ejecuta, el valor de `this` es el elemento creado (`eg: script`). Teniendo en cuenta esto, podrías simplemente crear una propiedad al elemento `script`, por ejemplo `targetId`, donde almacenar el valor de `j + 1` (*el `id` del elemento a actualizar*). Luego en el `onerror`, bastaría con llamar a `get_error(this.targetId);`.

Ejemplo:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
var pagina = ['pepito.html', 'IndexModeloWeb3.html', 'ProgressBar2.html', 'ProgressBar.html']
for (var t = 0; t < pagina.length; t++) {

  var mensaje = pagina[t];

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var element1 = document.createTextNode(mensaje);
  cell1.appendChild(element1);

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell2.id = t + 1;
  var element2 = document.createTextNode("")
  cell2.appendChild(element2);
}

function get_error(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = " does not exist.";
}


for (var j = 0; j < pagina.length; j++) {

  var el = document.createElement('script');
  el.onerror = function() {
    get_error(this.targetId);
  }
  el.targetId = j + 1;
  el.src = pagina[j];
  document.body.append(el);
}
```

```html
<table id="dataTable"></table>
```

Comment: Si señor!!! PERFECTO muchisimas gracias!!